# Angular dynamic list with matDatepicker

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to load a list, where I already have the data, however the matDatepicker, will be dynamic, the user will fill in to save to the bank.

```
<mat-list cols="3" rowHeight="2:1" *ngFor="let phase of budget.phases; let i = index">

    <h3 mat-subheader>
        {{ i + 1 }}. {{ phase.name }}
    </h3>

    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="phase.dateStart" placeholder="{{ 'fields.plannedStart' | translate }}"
        (focus)="dateStart.open()"
        (click)="dateStart.open()" readonly />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateStart"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dateStart></mat-datepicker>

    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="phase.dateEnd" placeholder="{{ 'fields.expectedDelivery' | translate }}"
        (focus)="dateEnd.open()"
        (click)="dateEnd.open()" readonly />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateEnd"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dateEnd></mat-datepicker>

</mat-list>
```

Only because it is a list, it returns an error, because it is repeating the dateStart and dateEnd, how can I resolve, so that it does not return the error.

I tried something like:

```
 <input matInput [matDatepicker]="phase.dateStart" placeholder="{{ 'fields.plannedStart' | translate }}"
        (focus)="dateStart_i.open()"
        (click)="dateStart_i.open()" readonly />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateStart_i"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dateStart_i></mat-datepicker>
```

Return

> ERROR Error: Attempted to open an MatDatepicker with no associated input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot create dynamic template variable names** like you are trying with `#dateStart_i` **and you don't have to** because each item in the ngFor will be isolated from the others because it will in its own instance of the template used for by the ngFor. I think that your problem is:

```html
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="phase.dateStart" placeholder="{{ 'fields.plannedStart' | translate }}"
        (focus)="dateStart_i.open()"
        (click)="dateStart_i.open()" readonly />
```

the matDatepicker directive should accept the datepicker template variable that should reference the mat-datepicker element and not `phase.dateStart`. If you have #dateStart and #dateEnd inside your template on the `mat-datepicker` components your start date input should look like:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateStart" ... />
```

and the same but using the dateEnd template variable for the end date input.

Checkout the datepicker [demos](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples).

The first example shows exactly how you should use the matDatepicker directive:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="picker.open()">Open</button>
```